# How to save Gmail emoticons/emojis to use on other apps

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, emoji, emojipedia

I like Gmail **style**/**design** of emoticons/emojis:

[image: Gmail emoticons/emojis]

How can I save them as PNG/JPEG to be imported on other applications like Slack? Slack allows importing emojis as PNG/JPEG files.

Ideally, is there any place where I can download them all as an archive/ZIP file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are most likely to be updated soon because they are outdated. The latest emoji icon pack was released by Google as part of **Android 9.0 Pie** in August 2018 and it can be found and downloaded at: **https://emojipedia.org/google/android-9.0/**

The design you are looking for is an old Android 7.1 emoji pack released on October 2016: **https://emojipedia.org/google/android-7.1/**